# using pandas to remove everything that comes after / inside sentences

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a csv file containing sentences that some has / in like shown in the picture

[image]

I'm trying to go though all sentences and whenever a / comes just remove what every comes after it ny expected output is something like that

[image]

what I tried until now is finding the slashes but how to remove what comes after them.

```
tdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput)

pat = '[' + re.escape("/") + ']'
df=tdata[tdata['sentences'].str.contains(pat, regex=True, na=False)]
```

Comment: Is possible text version of data? Because is not possible copy them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with one or no spaces `\s*` and `/` and then select first lists by `str[0]`:

```
tdata['English'] = tdata['English'].str.split('\s*/').str[0]
```

Or you can remove possible whitepaces after by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
tdata['English'] = tdata['English'].str.split('/').str[0].str.strip()
```

Comment: but will it remove them if the / is attached to the word like hello sarah/ hi sarah ?

Comment: because sometimes there is no space

Comment: @jezrael 2nd part of your answer is same as my answer.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - hmmm, I cannot see `strip` in your answer.

Comment: @jezrael Fine if you say so.

Comment: Highlight: `.str[x]` can be used to slice list items in a Series